Evaluating a sum of floors - Apostol number theory exercise 3.19a

Given positive odd integers $h$ and $k$, $(h,k)=1$, let $a=\frac{k-1}{2}$, $b=\frac{h-1}{2}$. Prove that
$$\sum_{r=1}^a \Big\lfloor\frac{h}{k}r\Big\rfloor + \sum_{r=1}^b \Big\lfloor\frac{k}{h}r\Big\rfloor = ab$$

I got stuck right from the start so I searched from some hints online and found this thing:

Define the rectangle $R$ to be the rectangle with corners at $(1,1)$ and $(h,k)$. Counting, we see the number of lattice points with even entries inside $R$ is $ab$. Now the first sum in question counts the number of lattice points with even entries in $R$ on or above $s$ (the line from $(0,0)$ to $(h,k)$), whereas the second sum counts the number of lattice points with even entries on or below the line. Since there are no lattice points on $s$, these sums add to $ab$.

Probably I'm missing some proprieties because I don't know where the bold part comes from (everything else is clear). How can I prove that? Can you please help me or maybe give some reference?

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread Simple floor identities, especially its Post #$2$, which shows with some pictures what you're asking about. There's also the related, but currently unanswered, ...

(cont.) Algebraic proof for $\sum_{r=1}^a\left\lfloor\frac{hr}k\right\rfloor+\sum_{r=1}^b\left\lfloor\frac{kr}h\right\rfloor=ab$.
